# Build Fails for VS 2008 while using Code for 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I used a code from 'instant results for ASP.NET 2.0' from IMAR Spa.... of WROX and modified the code using VS 2005 and then build it was very good for me but recently got the attack of folder virus. so i was to remove my VS 2005 and Upgraded the system as well.

Later on I installed VS 2008 and copied whole of the code in to a VS 2008 Project from VS 2005 code base and modified the code as per my needs and published as well.

But as per the requirements Earlier this month on 1 OCT 2011, i upgraded My VS 2008 with SP1 build from Microsoft since then i am getting build failed error and also no able to trace any errors in it. to remove this i again removed whole of the windows Installation and get on with initial IDE but still i am getting the same error.

could you please tell me if the last publish on previous windows with SP1 had wrote in my Settings files or did any others changes in my code which is causing build failed with out any errors. because i have used the same code always to build.

I cannot revert the changes as my code contains more then 1200 folders and more then 100000 files and is more then 300 MB in size. i have used Jquery, Javascript, Vb.net files, cs.net files, Sitemaps, DB's, etc in my website. please could any one help me debugging and publishing my website.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are several possible results related to this issue and can be given here in as Follows find your Cause and resolve the bug.

1. You can look in the Output window. If that doesn't provide enough detail,
   you can change the level of detail with Tools->Options->Projects and
   Solutions->Build and Run: MSBuild project build output verbosity.
2. Have you ever had Visual Studio tell you your web application publish failed, but never gives you a reason why? You’re not alone. I’ve been putting off looking into this issue on a project and just found a way to get my answer right away. Visual Studio 2008's Publish Failed message.
   Here’s what you should do inside of Visual Studio to find out why your publish failed.
3. Click the Tools menu > then Options to bring up the Options dialog.
4. Expand ‘Projects and Solutions’ on the left and click General
5. On General, click ‘Show Output window when build starts’
6. Now click on ‘Build and Run’ in the left tree
7. Next select a value from the ‘MSBuild project build output verbosity’ drop down menu
8. OK your way back to the main Visual Studio window
9. The next time you Build or Publish your project, you should see the Output panel pop up. If your publish is still failing, the answer will live inside the Output panel
10. Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General
    Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run
    Visual Studio's Output Panel
11. You need to consult the Output window for more information.
    View > Output
    or
    `Ctrl+Alt+O`

4.
Hi,
If we create a simple ASP.NET website and publish it using your VS 2008, does it have the same issue? If you are using Vista or Win 7, please try to run VS 2008 as Administrator. To troubleshoot the issue, you also can change "MSBuild project build output verbosity" option from (Tools menu, click Options, and then select the Projects and Solutions folder and click Build and Run) to
get detailed build steps.

5.
MSBuild does a good job of reporting build errors, but MSBuild can only report errors
that the underlying Tasks report. Custom tasks add a lot of variation to quality of the
error messages. Case in point is the following message, which popped up as a deadline
loomed.
Build FAILED.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:05.85
The build failed, but there are no errors to report. Yup. It's strange messages like this
that make me want to curse in German, but I don't know German, so I make the noises an
angry Klingon might make after living in Berlin for 5 years.
I couldn't find any problems in the output until I set MSBuild for maximum verbosity
(/verbosity:diagnostic, /v:diag for short), at which point I found this in the output:
Done building target "PrepareRdlFiles" in project "...".
Target "RunRdlCompiler" in file "...":
Building target "RunRdlCompiler" completely.
Output file "obj\Debug\RdlCompile.compiled" does not exist.
Using "RdlCompile" task from assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common ...".
Task "RdlCompile"
Done executing task "RdlCompile" -- FAILED.
Done building target "RunRdlCompiler" in project "CareAlertsWeb.csproj" -- FAILED.
Someone had added .rdlc files to the project. These are "Client Report Definition" files -
think of Reporting Services reports without a report server. Something was going wrong
compiling the .rdlc files, but there still wasn't any information to determine what the
problem was. Without knowing what else to do I started looking at the RdlCompile task
with Reflector.
The RdlCompile task is interesting. The task doesn't compile files in the traditional sense
(transform inputs into outputs). The task validates the report definition inside the .rdlc
file. This step ensures we'll get compile time errors instead of runtime errors from the
ReportViewer control if the report definition is invalid.
The assembly hosting RdlCompile referenced another assembly that was not on the build
machine (Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel). Mysterious. Why this caused
the task to fail without reporting a more specific error is also a mystery.
With all the assemblies were in place, the RdlCompile task finished with success. Running
ReportViewer.exe installs all the required assemblies, you can find it in %Program
Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\ReportViewer.

6.
If you select this option, the markup is left as-is, allowing you to change HTML and client-side functionality after precompiling the Web site. Selecting this option is equivalent to adding the -u option to the aspnet_compiler.exe command. For more information, see Precompiling for Deployment with Updatable UI and ASP.NET C ompilation Tool (Aspnet_compiler.exe).

a). If you want to be able to update individual pages by recompiling them, select Use fixed naming and single page assemblies. This option might degrade the performance of a very large site. For more information, see the following
topics:
Precompiling to Fixed-Name Assemblies
ASP.NET C ompilation Tool (Aspnet_compiler.exe).
How to: Generate Fixed Names with the ASP.NET C ompilation Tool
b). If you want to be able to debug in the published Web site, select Emit debug information.
c). To create strongly named assemblies using a key file or a key container, select the Enable strong
naming on precompiled assemblies check box, select the appropriate radio button, and enter the
appropriate information Key file location or Key container box.
Strong-named assemblies can be deployed to the server's global assembly cache (GAC ) or to the Bin
directory of the application. A signed assembly makes it more difficult for malicious users to replace the
application's assemblies with malicious code. However, the complexity of key management in shared
development environments might outweigh the advantages of signed assemblies. For information about
strong-naming on assemblies, see the following topics:
Precompiling to Signed Assemblies
ASP.NET C ompilation Tool (Aspnet_compiler.exe)
How to: Sign Assemblies for Precompiled Web Site Projects
d). If you select Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies, and if you use a key file, and if
you want to delay the signing of the key file, select Delay signing.
If you select this option, the assembly is signed in two stages: first with the public key file, and then with
a private key file that is specified later during a call to the aspnet_compiler.exe command.
e). If you selected Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies, and if you want to allow the
assemblies to be called by partially trusted code, select Mark assemblies with
AllowPartiallyTrustedCallerAttribute (APTCA).
Assemblies must have the AllowPartiallyTrustedC allersAttribute attribute to be called by the ASP.NET
runtime. For more information, see AllowPartiallyTrustedC allersAttribute.
f). C lick OK.
Publishing status is displayed in the taskbar. When publishing is completed, the status of Publish
succeeded is displayed.

7.
The answer in the end was that it is a known bug:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=317870
The answer is to modify project files (*.csproj) containing LINQ to SQL dbml files to remove some stuff, as
follows:
a. Close VS 2008.
b. Open the project file containing the LINQ To SQL item in Notepad.
c. Remove the following lines:

```
[ItemGroup]
[Service Include="{3259AA49-8AA1-44D3-9025-A0B520596A8C}"/]
[/ItemGroup]
```

The Setup Project will now build successfully. However, if you double-click the DBML file to open the designer in VS 2008 the Setup Project will stop building again. The above lines do not get re-added to the project file but the Setup Project will stop building anyway. Just restart VS 2008 and it will work again -- until you open the DBML designer again. Once the Setup Project fails due to this problem it will never build successfully until after you restart VS 2008.

8.
Another workaround listed worked : right click on the solution and click "Clean Solution" in Visual Studio

9.
You can edit a csproj file in VS without closing the solution: 1. from the project context menu unload the project, 2. from the context menu open the csproj file in VS, 3. edit & save, 4. from the context menu re-open the project

10.
Firstly, right-click on your Solution file > Properties > Configuration
In there, use the build tick boxes to experiment with which projects build together, and which don't. Also, in your file system, delete the debug/release folders for all of your projects.
Finally, in my experience, this error is usually caused by a corrupt/missing web.config

11.
Sometimes you get better error messages if you track down the build command (its in the output
windows) and looks like
E:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /errorrep...blah..blah
Then run that manually at the command line. Also, the output window tends to have better information, even though Visual Studios default behavior is to show the "Errors List" window after a failed build.

12.
When you say cleaning, you mean Right Clicking on the Solutions and clicking Clean Solutions?
Have you tried removing all the built dlls from the Bin folder manually and making sure no other running applications have files open. Not sure if its sill an issue with VS, but files or folders starting with a "." can cause problems. eg if SubVersion is not set to use "_svn" instead of ".svn"

13.
Try moving the project root the root of the drive. I had run into an issue with a very large project where the path length was so long it had started to cause issues.
So rather than:
c:\My Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\\PrecompiledWeb\..........\abc.xyz
do this: c:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\..........\abc.xyz
here  Describes the name of the system User,    Project name and   ..........\abc.xyz Describes files and folders inside the project which was created by user. Or can reduce to c:\Publish\..........\abc.xyz or to   c:\..........\abc.xyz

14.
and in the last but not the least I must say :- 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/345523/2008-web-deployment-projects-wdp-fail-build-without-error-when-the-visual-studio-2008-sdk-is-installed

If 2008 Web Deployment Projects is installed and the Visual Studio 2008 SDK is NOT installed, Web Deployment Projects will build successfully.
If both 2008 Web Deployment Projects and the Visual Studio 2008 SDK are installed, Web Deployment Project builds will fail, but there will be no error messages.
If the Visual Studio 2008 SDK is uninstalled and the 2008 Web Deployment Projects installation is left unmodified, Web Deployment Projects will again build successfully.
It is important to note that no code in the solution (including both the Web Application Project and the Web Deployment Project) attempts to use the Visual Studio 2008 SDK in any way. The mere presence of the VS 2008 SDK on the system seems to corrupt the build process for Web Deployment Projects, even for a basic "Hello World" web application.
Two files are attached--
* Log - This is a log file of a Build attempt while the Visual Studio 2008 SDK is installed, with the log level set to "Diagnostic"
* Zip - This is a very basic solution that contains a "Hello World" Web Application Project and a corresponding Web Deployment Project. If the Visual Studio 2008 SDK is installed, this Web Deployment Project will fail to build, but there will be no errors. If the Visual Studio SDK is NOT installed, the entire solution will build successfully.